# Getting material-ui components to appear inline by overriding style props

Tags: css, material-ui

I am trying to get a check box to appear to the right of the input field "answer input one" I have tried playing with the display property but am really struggling with css layouts in general.[what I am currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS8Uo.png)

Here is the code that is rendering the answer input:

```
     <div>
  <TextField
  hintText="An informative question title..."
  fullWidth
  floatingLabelText="Question Title"
  value={questionTitle}
  onChange={(e) => this.props.questionTitleChanged(e.target.value)}
  />
  <TextField
  floatingLabelText="Answer Input 1"
  onChange={(e) => this.props.questionInputChanged({
    inputIndex: 0,
    value: e.target.value,
    correct: false
  })}
  value={questionInputs[0].value}
  style={styles.answerField}
  />

  <Checkbox
  onCheck={() => {
    let correctOrIncorrect = null;

    if (questionInputs[0].correct) {
      correctOrIncorrect = false;
    } else { correctOrIncorrect = true; }

    this.props.questionInputChanged({
    inputIndex: 0,
    value: null,
    correct: correctOrIncorrect });
  }}
  style={styles.checkbox}
  />

  </div>
```

And the inline styles are here:

```
const styles = {
  createQuizContainer: {
    width: '70%',
    margin: 'auto',
    paddingTop: 30,
    paddingBottom: 40
  },
  answerField: {
    width: '70%',
  },
  checkBox: {
    display: 'inline',
  }

};
```

and help would be greatly appreciated! As well as any advice on layouts with css in general!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use flexbox:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
            <div>
                <TextField />
            </div>
            <div style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                <Checkbox />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2v1Legy2/1/

Comment: you're very welcome. if this answer worked for you, could you please set to "Answered" ? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css for the checkbox to:

```
checkbox: {
    float: 'right',
    width: '10%',
    marginTop: '7%'
  }
```

as is was previously full width. Not a great solution but gets there anyhow